# Page Routes using list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a widget as inkwell to navigate to other pages in my app.
The problem is that I have more than one page and I want to assign different routes to the same widget.
I thought we could do this by using a list of strings or classes but it didn't work.

So my question is how to assign different page routes to the same widget as button.

This is my widget inkWell.

```
  Widget mainTestName(String testName, String image, String des, Color color) {
    return Expanded(
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QuestionTypes1()));
            },
```

Here I want to assign the various names of the pages

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QuestionTypes1()));
```

I thought we could use a list of Strings or Classes or PageRoutes but it didn't work. Like this

```
List<PageRoute> pageRoutes = [
  QuestionTypes1;
  QuestionTypes2;
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, in that way you are doing you can set different routes using a list passing the respective page from your list, to where you want navigate. Your code should be something like this. Note that instead of a list of PageRoutes you pass a list of Widgets that are your pages, that must extend a StatefulWidget or a StatelessWidget as well.

```
//List of pages
List<Widget> pageRoutes = [
  QuestionTypes1(), //pageRoutes[0]
  QuestionTypes2(), // pageRoutes[1]
  ];

    //Add the page argument to your method signature:
    Widget mainTestName(String testName, String image, String des, Color color, Widget page) {
      return Expanded(
                child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
                    },),);
     }
```

Then you pass the page by the index of your list:

```
Widget mainTestName('testName', 'image', 'des', 'color', pageRoutes[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @JRamos29. But as soon as I typed the list, it generated an error    Expected to find ']'.  and underlined the ; as an error.

Comment: You must separate the items of the list with comma (,) instead of semicolon(;). See the example i wrote.